# C# WPF User Control with Textbox, TextBlock and Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I created the following user control that consists of:
- TextBlock : Contains the description of the path to be inserted
- TextBox : Contains the name of directory
- Button : Lets you search for a directory in your pc and put it in the textbox

```
  public partial class TextBrowse : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  if (PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SetName =
  DependencyProperty.Register("BlockName", typeof(string), typeof(TextBrowse),
  new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(
  (obj, chng) =>
  {
    (obj as TextBrowse).BlockName = (string)chng.NewValue;
  }
  ))); 
}
public string BlockName
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(SetName); }
  set { SetValue(SetName, value); }
}
private Type _T;
public Type T
{
  set { _T = value; }
  get { return _T; }
}
public enum Type { File, Folder }
public TextBrowse()
{
  InitializeComponent(); 
  if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
    return;
}
private void CButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (_T == Type.File)
  {
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      this.DirectoryName = ofd.FileName;
  }
  else
  {
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      CTextbox.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
  }
}
public string DirectoryName
{
  get
  {
    return (string)this.GetValue(DirectoryNameProperty);
  }
  set
  {
    this.SetValue(DirectoryNameProperty, value);
  }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty DirectoryNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "TextName", typeof(string), typeof(TextBrowse), new PropertyMetadata(""));}
```

This is the XAML code

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXX.TextBrowse"
         x:Name="TB"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DirectoryName, ElementName=TB, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="CTextBlock" Margin="4" Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row="0"/> 
<Button Name="CButton" Margin="4" Grid.Column = "1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Browse" Click="CButton_Click" />
<TextBox Name="CTextbox" Margin="4" Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

And I would like to call it that way from a window

```
    xmlns:custom ="clr-namespace:XXX"
Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
   <custom:TextBrowse BlockName="Name of TextBlock"/>
</Grid>
```

And the result is the dynamic creation of the user control.
In the name of the TextBlock is the value entered in BlockName
When a path is selected by means of the button is inserted in the texbox.

As I did I did not work
Best regard

Comment: Hi Delta. what exactly didn't (or doesn't) work?

Comment: FYI Controls do not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Notification is done by the DependencyProperty

Comment: The name of a static dependency property identifier field should follow a naming convention, i.e. `<PropertyName>Property`, so yours should be `BlockNameProperty` instead of `SetName`. You also don't need to re-assign the property value in its PropertyChangedCallback. That makes no sense.

Comment: the error is: Error 35 Could not create an instance of type 'TextBrowse'.

Answer (score 0):

You should change to this.

```
public partial class TextBrowse : UserControl
{

public static readonly DependencyProperty SetName =DependencyProperty.Register("BlockName", typeof(string), typeof(TextBrowse),new PropertyMetadata(null); 
public string BlockName
{
   get { return (string)GetValue(SetName); }
   set { SetValue(SetName, value); }
}
private Type _T;
public Type T
{
   set { _T = value; }
   get { return _T; }
}
public enum Type { File, Folder }
public TextBrowse()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
private void CButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (_T == Type.File)
   {
          OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
          if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             this.DirectoryName = ofd.FileName;
    }
  else
  {
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        CTextbox.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
   }
}
public string DirectoryName
{
    get
    {
       return (string)this.GetValue(DirectoryNameProperty);
    }
    set
    {
       this.SetValue(DirectoryNameProperty, value);
    }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty DirectoryNameProperty =DependencyProperty.Register("TextName", typeof(string), typeof(TextBrowse), new PropertyMetadata(""));}
```